# Is one obligated to do professional work for one's father or Rav?

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

If a father / a Rav asks his son/student to do a professional job for him, like fixing a PC, painting a room or replacing a faucet in the kitchen, and they pay all the expenses but not the wage,

**Is one obligated to the job**, if he is able to, whether he's a professional technician or painter etc or not, or because it is a professional work people do for the living he would be exempt?

I could only find the following reference: Gm' [Ketubot 96a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=96&format=pdf) and also [Rambam](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910979/jewish/Talmud-Torah-Chapter-Five.htm) and [Yoreh Deah 242:19](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%98):

> "אמר רבי יהושע בן לוי, **כל מלאכות שהעבד עושה לרבו** תלמיד עושה לרבו"

but it seems to cover only unprofessional common tasks.